# Floating point IEEE guarantees

Tags: floating-point, standards, operations, ieee

I would like to know, for the following cases, if the IEEE standard guarantees every possible case (excluding NaN and infinities) using any cpu adhering to the standard:

- Commutativity: x # y = y # x
- Associativity: (x # y) # z = x # (y # z)
- x - x = 0 (does x - x == 0.0f always return true?)
- x * 0 = 0 (does x * 0.0f == 0.0f always return true?)
- x * 1 = x (does x * 1.0f == x always return true?)
- x / x = 1.0f (does x / x == 1.0f always return true? Except for x = 0 of course)

(# means all operations: + - * /)

Comment: Associativity can't be guaranteed with floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Commutativity: `+` and `*` are guaranteed unless either argument is `NaN`. `-` and `/` are not commutative and division by `0.0` gives you `+Inf`, `-Inf`, or `NaN` according to the numerator. Here I'm not giving any consideration to *signed zeros*.
2. Associativity. Absolutely not. The addition of two small numbers followed by a large number is a counter-example.
3. `x - x` is `0` unless `x` is `NaN`, `+Inf`, or `-Inf` in which case it is `NaN`.
4. `x * 0` is `0` unless `x` is `NaN`, `+Inf`, or `-Inf` in which case it is `NaN`.
5. `x * 1` is `x` unless `x` is `NaN` in which case it is `NaN`.
6. `x / x` is `1` unless x is `0.0`, `+Inf`, `-Inf`, or `NaN` in which case it is `NaN`.

Note the subtle difference of (5).

Comment: Commutativity is a little bit subtle if you care about NaN signs and/or payloads: if both `x` and `y` are NaNs, with different payloads, then `x + y` and `y + x` may not be identical. It's not unusual for `x + y` to be identical to `x`, and `y + x` to be identical to `y`. (The standard doesn't specify, though: it just says  "the result shall be a quiet NaN which should be one of the input NaNs")

Comment: Hmm. Actually, on my macOS machine, it looks as though `x + y` where `x` and `y` are qNaNs with different payloads returns the _second_ operand `y`.

Comment: (1) was only partially correct. Commutativity is not guaranteed for NaN. (I think a processor will probably treat NaN in the same way as a signed zero.)

Comment: For signed zeros, though, the rules about the result are completely specified by the standard, and commutativity will hold. It's only NaNs where there's a possibility of non-commutativity (and even then, only if you care about payloads and signs; for many uses of NaNs, they don't matter).

Comment: I think I'm going to wiki this: perhaps it does need more detail. I think I'm getting confused with `std::max` &c. for signed zero and zero arguments. My disclaiming consideration for signed zeros is a little indolent.